# How do I get JSON from this page source? I've tried countless different methods all haven't worked

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, urllib, tiktok

Currently here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen

user = "khaby.lame"
u = urlopen("https://tiktok.com/@" + user).read()
soup = bs4(u, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Now, what this code does is returns the entire page source as you'd probably know, which is good but now I've got the page source (the text in the variable "soup") I want to get the "UserModule" JSON data from the page source and only that. It's kind of hard to explain but I hope I made it clear to understand. One of the things I want to obtain from "UserModule" is the User ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiktok's `UserModule` data is in the JSON contained in the `innerHTML` of `script#SIGI_STATE`.

To get this data, you can use `soup.select` to get the `script#SIGI_STATE` element and `.encode_contents()` to get the `innerHTML` of the element to get a JSON containing `UserModule` data. Do some data retrieve from that JSON.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

user = "khaby.lame"
u = urlopen("https://tiktok.com/@" + user).read()
soup = bs4(u, "html.parser")
allData = json.loads(soup.select('script#SIGI_STATE')[0].encode_contents().decode('utf8'))
UserModule = allData['UserModule']
id = UserModule['users'][user]['id']
print(json.dumps(UserModule, indent=4))
print(id)
```

The output will be:

```json
{
    "users": {
        "khaby.lame": {
            "id": "127905465618821121",
            "shortId": "",
            "uniqueId": "khaby.lame",
            "nickname": "Khabane lame",
            "avatarLarger": "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/793e825b068a0ef5444e86e55812965a~c5_1080x1080.jpeg?x-expires=1682535600&x-signature=Q53PyPjeWtXAYXvtRT3kJjhrLMk%3D",
            "avatarMedium": "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/793e825b068a0ef5444e86e55812965a~c5_720x720.jpeg?x-expires=1682535600&x-signature=xG2MLx%2FQP%2FsE8pnQBtPngdY%2F6KI%3D",
            "avatarThumb": "https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-avt-0068/793e825b068a0ef5444e86e55812965a~c5_100x100.jpeg?x-expires=1682535600&x-signature=Di%2FC22QjiIBm0Ors%2FrnkNWFEGgg%3D",
            "signature": "Se vuoi ridere sei nel posto giusto\ud83d\ude0e \nIf u wanna laugh u r in the right place\ud83d\ude0e",
            "createTime": 0,
            "verified": true,
            "secUid": "MS4wLjABAAAAwAg0rSzO65WQfz4RzQgGv2Xdv108BgPXhRrrmNVIHQZ9PO8-flwwRtEppYTS0OjA",
            "ftc": false,
            "relation": 0,
            "openFavorite": false,
            "commentSetting": 0,
            "commerceUserInfo": {
                "commerceUser": false
            },
            "duetSetting": 0,
            "stitchSetting": 0,
            "privateAccount": false,
            "secret": false,
            "isADVirtual": false,
            "roomId": "",
            "uniqueIdModifyTime": 0,
            "ttSeller": false,
            "region": "IT",
            "downloadSetting": 0,
            "profileTab": {
                "showMusicTab": false,
                "showQuestionTab": false,
                "showPlayListTab": false
            },
            "followingVisibility": 1,
            "recommendReason": "",
            "nowInvitationCardUrl": "",
            "nickNameModifyTime": 0,
            "isEmbedBanned": false,
            "canExpPlaylist": true,
            "profileEmbedPermission": 1,
            "extraInfo": {
                "statusCode": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "stats": {
        "khaby.lame": {
            "followerCount": 156900000,
            "followingCount": 78,
            "heart": 2300000000,
            "heartCount": -2033648397,
            "videoCount": 1085,
            "diggCount": 0,
            "needFix": true
        }
    }
}
127905465618821121
```

Comment: @a️️ just run it via Python notebook. Create file `test.ipynb`, put your code, install some vsc extensions, and run. Hope that helps.